# Ошибка сборки: Невозможно запустить процесс

Tags: сборка, qt, c++

Гугление ничего не дало. Кто-то сталкивался?

```
04:11:50: Выполняются этапы для проекта Matrix...
04:11:50: Невозможно запустить процесс «C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\qmake.exe» C:\Projects\Matrix\Matrix.pro -r -spec win32-g++
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта Matrix (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.3 MinGW 32bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «qmake»
04:11:50: Прошло времени: 00:00.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Зашел в настройки проекта и снял птичку с "Теневая сборка", всё заработало.